# first time in phpMyAdmin, error #1064 pops up

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, xampp

this is my first time using phpMyAdmin and I was trying to import a sample database when this line of text happened,

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'source load_departments.dump' at line 1

as I went and checked the error it was in this line

```
SELECT 'LOADING departments' as 'INFO';
source load_departments.dump ;
```

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you aren't able to `SOURCE` — that is, import other arbitrary files — from within phpMyAdmin. You could use the MySQL command line client or rename `load_departments.dump` to `load_departments.sql` and import that file through the phpMyAdmin interface manually.

If I recall correctly, the source command is a construct of the MySQL command line client and isn't actually a valid SQL command.